# Keeping chapter titles in table of contents but deleting the chapters in the document

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I am writing a book that I will publish in two separate volumes. In volume 1,  I want the table of contents to show the full list of chapters for volume 1 and volume 2, however I do not want volume 2 chapters to be included in published version of volume 1. How do I remove the chapters from volume 2 without removing the chapter titles for volume 2 from the table of contents in volume 1 ?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263297/merging-aux-files

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this 
**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
% packages

\begin{document}
\input{volumeI}
\input{volumeII}
\end{document}
```

**volumeI.tex**

```
bla bla
\tableofcontents
bla bla 
\chapter{Foo}
bla bla
```

**volumeII.tex**

```
bla bla
\tableofcontents
bla bla 
\chapter{Foo}
bla bla
```

compile main.tex as necessary and then comment `%\input{volumeII}` and recompile once.