# Merging aux files

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files

The aux file basically consists of tex commands which are read and expanded at the begining of the document.  The command

```
\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\input{test2.aux}\makeatother}
```

will have pretty much the same effect, at least in terms of `\newlabel` commands.  OTOH, `\@writefile{toc}` commands don't fare as well.  Perhaps this has to do with the fact that the `\@starttoc{toc}` command is the one which actually writes the toc.

Anyway, I am trying to merge the table of contents without actually repeating the entire document each time.  The following was used to create `test2.aux`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setcounter{part}{1}
\setcounter{page}{11}% this you will have to do manually
\part{Volume 2}
\chapter{v2 first}\label{test}
\chapter{v2 second}
\end{document}
```

which is read by

```
\documentclass{book}
\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\input{test2.aux}\makeatother}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Volume 1}
\chapter{v1 first}\pageref{test}%\newlabel{test} from test2.aux
\chapter{v1 second}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\pageref{test}` works.

Comment: isn't it easier to input the `toc` from the other document rather than the `aux` ? (`xr.sty` use \read to selectively pick labels (only) from another aux file exactly to avoid problems with other things that are there)

Comment: @David Carlisle - Well, you certainly wouldn't want to use this with hyperref, and you may want to use custom \label and \ref macros to handle the volume numbers (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263015/abbreviate-ref-within-same-section/263142#263142), but for printed documents, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an `\input` statement literally written to the `.aux` file at the end of the document. The key is not to use `\immediate\write` but `\write` only.

```
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
    \write\@auxout{%
       \string\input{test2.aux}
      % Other \string\input{test3.aux} etc. here 
     }%
 }
\makeatother
```

will write `\input{test2.aux}` at the document end and not somewhere in between. Other files to be included can be added with `\string\input{test3.aux}` etc.

For better checks, `\InputIfFileExists{}{}{}` should be used, but I've omitted this feature for simplicity right now.

```
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter

\AtEndDocument{%
    \write\@auxout{%
      \string\input{test2.aux}
      % Other \string\input{test3.aux} etc. here 
    }%
 }
\makeatother

%\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\input{test2.aux}\makeatother}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Volume 1}
\chapter{v1 first}\pageref{test}%\newlabel{test} from test2.aux
\chapter{v1 second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the content of `foo.aux` (the merging document):

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{I\hspace  {1em}Volume 1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}v1 first}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}v1 second}{5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\input{test2.aux}
```

Comment: a `\write` at end of document isn't guaranteed to happen (it happens at the next page shipout but there may not be any further pages).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I am aware of the possible breakdown with `'\write`. It might fail. An `\immediate\write` did not work

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of Hupfer's solution which allows all the projects to share aux files.  Project `test`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newif\iffirstaux
\firstauxtrue
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \write\@auxout{\string\iffirstaux
     \string\firstauxfalse
     \string\InputIfFileExists{test2.aux}{}{}%
     \string\firstauxtrue
     \string\fi}%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Volume 1}
\chapter{v1 first}\pageref{test}%\newlabel{test} from test2.aux
\chapter{v1 second}
\end{document}
```

Project `test2`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newif\iffirstaux
\firstauxtrue
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \write\@auxout{\string\iffirstaux
     \string\firstauxfalse
     \string\InputIfFileExists{test.aux}{}{}%
     \string\firstauxtrue
     \string\fi}%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setcounter{part}{1}
\setcounter{page}{11}% this you will have to do manually
\part{Volume 2}
\chapter{v2 first}\label{test}
\chapter{v2 second}
\end{document}
```

Note that the aux files have to be `\input` in order, some at the beginning and some at the end.